# Share Buttons Dont Appear On The Homepage

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm having issues with the share buttons I've coded in my blog, the URL of the blog is as follows - http://www.blankesque.com. The icons appear perfectly how I've coded them to appear everywhere else on the blog - tab pages, post pages etc - apart from in archive pages, search pages, label pages and importantly the homepage. I don't have any conditional tags on the coding, for the share buttons to only appear in certain pages.

I have a small doubt whether the margin and padding values I have coded for the share buttons may play a role in this but even when I adjusted the values on numerous occasions the problem was still very much evident.

The html and css coding I'm using is as follows:

```
<div class='sharebtns'>
<a class='twitter' expr:href='&quot;https://twitter.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;title=&quot; + data:post.title' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Tweet This'><img alt='Tweet This' border='0' height='25px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/A036F9A7-1B42-42A6-9DF4-29FE498F231D_zpshfhfvks2.jpg' width='25px'/></a>
<a class='email' expr:href='&quot;mailto:?subject=&quot; + data:post.title + &quot;&amp;body=&quot; + data:post.url' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Share Via Email'><img alt='Share Via Email' border='0' height='25px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/45AA973D-D8A1-4FAE-A31A-138DA7CB8443_zpsteklwczz.jpg' width='25px'/></a>
<a class='facebook' expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;t=&quot; + data:post.title' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Share This On Facebook'><img alt='Facebook Share' border='0' height='25px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/234A9CED-06E8-4D0B-8377-A64D92B082A1_zpsbexuli8g.jpg' width='25px'/></a>
<a class='comment-form' expr:href='data:post.addCommentUrl' expr:onclick='data:post.addCommentOnclick.com' title='comment-form'><img alt='comment-form' border='0' height='25px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/48123A9F-FE25-4669-982E-36385779DACB_zpskf0c60io.jpg' width='25px'/></a>
 </div>
<style>
.sharebtns {
text-align: center;
margin: 8% 0% 6% 0%;
}
.sharebtns a {
padding: 0px 20px;
}
.sharebtns a:hover {
opacity: 0.2;
filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}
</style>
```

Any help in this regards would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you have some javascript errors on the home page that aren't on the post page. Javascript is pretty fragile at times and a single error one place can cause other javascript to fail as well. I recommend solving the javascript errors that come before the discuss error and see if that solves it for you.

Comment: Locke125, Thank you for getting in touch so quickly. Im very new to html, and my knowledge isn't broad enough to solve any javascript related issues. I cant personally see any javascript errors on the homepage but if you could aid me in that, then I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: If you open the developer console in your browser (usually the f12 key) you will see some tabs and one probably says `Console`. If you select it you will see the errors that are occuring on the page.

Comment: locke125 I have followed your instructions and I did indeed see two errors under the Console tab. However it says I have been denied access. Im logged in so Im not entirely sure why I have been denied access.

Comment: I was looking at this a bit more and I'm not clear on what the issue is. Something is not displaying right, but what and where? What are the specifics?

Comment: I have share buttons installed on my blog. And they should be displaying just above the jumplink in posts; I haven't applied any conditional tags. However the buttons don't appear on the posts that "preview" on the homepage but on individual posts the buttons do appear and in the exact place where they've been coded for. The buttons aren't displaying on the label, archive and search pages either.